# mini registeration popup

Tags: mini-cart, register, registration

i have mini register window , When i want to write Firstname and Lastname and Email and press submit the data didn't pass to create account page as you see in pic

[image]

[image]

any ideas please
Thank you

Comment: check out from Google. https://www.google.com/search?q=modal+popup+in+magento+2&rlz=1C1SQJL_enIN908IN908&oq=modal+popup+in+magento+2&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j0i22i30l4.6400j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: iam searching but i didn't found

Comment: Click on above link